# Multiple cells selection programmatically from a table in a webpage with javascript (chrome bug?)

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a selection similar to excel. I have a table, but this table comes from an external source. In this table when someone selects four cell (as excel B2:C3) I would like to create a selection which able to copy, paste, and other similar operations.

My cells - to keep things simple - are DOM elements, in these variables: b2, b3, c2, c3.

Relevant code part is here:

```
let range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(c3);
range.insertNode(c2);
range.insertNode(b3);
range.insertNode(b2);
let sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

But this code rearranges the DOM structure.

Here is the codepen to reproduce it: https://codepen.io/sarkiroka/pen/wvGRzdv

```js
function makeSelection(){
  let b2=document.getElementById('b2');
  let b3=document.getElementById('b3');
  let c2=document.getElementById('c2');
  let c3=document.getElementById('c3');
  let sel=window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  let range=document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(c3);
  range.insertNode(c2);
  range.insertNode(b3);
  range.insertNode(b2);
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="makeSelection()">Make Selection</button>
<br><br>
<table border=1 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td id="b2">B2</td>
    <td id="c2">C2</td>
    <td>D2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td id="b3">B3</td>
    <td id="c3">C3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>D4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The expected result is similar to what you see on the screenshot below (from excel). It's not just visual feedback (background color, font-color, border, etc), which I would like to have, but also to be able to copy the content of these cells to the clipboard for example.

[image: excel screenshot]

What do I do wrong?

PS: chrome-only, native js

Comment: If you want to implement "copy, paste and same other operations", you'll have to do a lot more than this. If it is not relevant for the question, then remove that part. If it is relevant to the question, then the question is too broad. For the actual code, also include expected result for that particular example.

Comment: @trincot The copy is the main functionality. Else I found many solution to visual feedback for the selection, but these solutions cannot to copied with clipboard

Comment: It seems we cannot add discontinuous nodes as range selection.You can consider disabling the browser selection and add custom selection.